# React-Native KeyboardAvoidingView not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please do not mark this as duplicate.It is not. I haven't found any working solution for me.

So basically, I have been browsing stackoverflow and GitHub and I could get nothing working for me. If I set the `behavior` of `KeyboardAvoidingView` to `padding` nothing happens. However, `position` or `height` works fine, just as intended. Anyone has any ideea why? I need padding here, specifically. It doesn't matter where I put my `KeyboardAvoidingView` tag or what I wrap with it, it won't work.

Basically I am trying to get the `<RichToolbar>` to get pushed up when i open the keyboard. Seems easy, lost a day on it :(

I also tried the package containing `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, no luck.

I am currently using

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.2
```

My code:

```
  return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior="position">
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView scrollEnabled={false} contentContainerStyle={styles.textEditorContainer}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <>
            <TextInput
              autoCorrect={false}
              style={styles.title}
              placeholder={Strings.screen.edit.titlePlaceholder}
              onChangeText={this.onTitleValueChange}
              value={titleValue}
            />
            {divider}
            <RichEditor
              ref={this.setEditorRef}
              initialContentHTML={this.props.initialEditorValue.content}
              style={styles.textEditor}
            />
          </>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        {this.renderCornerAnimation()}
        <View style={styles.toolbarContainer}>
          <RichToolbar
            style={styles.toolbar}
            getEditor={() => this.richText}
            iconTint={'#000033'}
            selectedIconTint={'#2095F2'}
            selectedButtonStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
  }

}

interface Style {
  container: ViewStyle;
  textEditorContainer: ViewStyle;
  textEditor: ViewStyle;
  title: TextStyle;
  toolbarContainer: ViewStyle;
  toolbar: ViewStyle;
  toolbarButton: TextStyle;
  lottieView: ViewStyle;
  divider: ViewStyle;
  iconSetContainerStyle: ViewStyle;
  textInput: ViewStyle;
}

function createStyleSheet(colorScheme: ColorScheme): Style {
  return StyleSheet.create<Style>({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      paddingTop: getStatusBarHeight(true),
      backgroundColor: color[colorScheme].background,
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    textEditorContainer: {
      width: screenWidth / 1.2,
      backgroundColor: palette.white[1],
      borderRadius: 40,
    },
    textEditor: {
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: palette.white[1],
    },
    title: {
      backgroundColor: palette.white[1],
      width: '100%',
      padding: 5,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
      borderTopRightRadius: 10,
      fontWeight: '700',
      fontSize: 20,
    },
    toolbarContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      minHeight: 35,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      backgroundColor: color[colorScheme].background,
      paddingBottom: getBottomSpace(),
    },
    toolbar: {
      height: 35,
      backgroundColor: color[colorScheme].background,
    },
    toolbarButton: {
      fontSize: 12,
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    lottieView: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
    },
    divider: {
      width: '10%',
      borderRadius: 4,
      marginLeft: 8,
      borderBottomWidth: 6,
    },
    iconSetContainerStyle: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    textInput: {
      color: color[colorScheme].text,
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `RichToolbar` view outside the `ScrollView`?

Comment: @giotskhada Yeah.. doesn't work. I don't get it, position and height does but padding doesn't

Comment: What exactly does it do? Is the `ScrollView` scrollable? If so, is the end of the `ScrollView` visible when you scroll all the way? Or does the keyboard cover some of it?

Comment: The scrollview isn't scrollable. I know it doesn't work because I trigger they ctrl + K shortcut for the keyboard to show up on XCode and I have time to see if it goes up or not.

Comment: Can you try setting `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop to different values (50, 100, 200) and see what happens?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421280/how-do-fix-the-white-keyboard-space-that-shows-whenever-i-use-keyboardawareview

Comment: Try this: `<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' keyboardVerticalOffset={50} style={{ flex: 1 }}>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro developer but try this hack....!

```
<View
        style={{ flex: 1, }}>

        <Modal
            visible={state}
            transparent={true}
        >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column-reverse', flex: 1 }}>
                <TextInput placeholder='wexneweyxuyfwwyfunwfyw' />
            </View>
        </Modal>

        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: color.rebeccapurple }}>
                <Text>Touch</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
```

This will auto align textInput on top of keyBoard Thanks ..

also run the fucntion easy .....